# Requirejs with nodejs doesn't tell me the line number of the error, just the error

Tags: node.js, requirejs, syntax-error

Requirejs with nodejs doesn't tell me the line number of the error, just the error

For example the result is: Error: Evaluating ccc.js as module "ccc" failed with error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

And then the stack:

```
at Function.req.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:2470:23)
at Object.context.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1858:21)
at Object.Module.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1059:29)
at Object.Module.fetch (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1049:66)
at Object.Module.check (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1079:26)
at Object.Module.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1376:22)
at Object.context.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1730:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1361:33)
at g (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:363:23)
at each (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:291:31)
at Object.Module.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1323:17)
at Object.Module.init (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1013:26)
at callGetModule (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1403:63)
at Object.context.completeLoad (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1763:21)
at Function.req.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:2510:17)
at Object.context.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1858:21)
at Object.Module.load (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1059:29)
at Object.Module.fetch (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1049:66)
at Object.Module.check (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1079:26)
at Object.Module.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1376:22)
at Object.context.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1730:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1361:33)
at g (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:363:23)
at each (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:291:31)
at Object.Module.enable (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1323:17)
at Object.Module.init (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1013:26)
at Object.context.makeRequire.mixin.isBrowser [as _onTimeout] (D:\web\pc\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1646:36)
at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

And where the error is? I know the file but what line?

thanks for help

Comment: can we see the code please as well?

Comment: I've already found the error. But this is not the problem, I would like to be shown in the console, like the line number where the error happened. There was an extra comma on line X, for example.

Comment: I have seen some people use - https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node - but I'm not sure whether this will serve you well. Give it a try though!

Comment: well, that just adds the time when something has been written to the console

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with requirejs and was fixed in nodejs version 0.12.

> Unfortunately, there are not enough hooks into vm.runInThisContext in
>   older node versions to get to the information.

More info you can find [here](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1152#issuecomment-73438269)

So, nodejs v.0.10 doesn't want to show additional info about problem. But if you want - you can install newest version of nodejs and gets more info about syntax errors in "required" files.

By the way, with [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) it's pretty easy - all you need just pull repo from node:0.12.